# Relational database(sqlite) for holding state information about a network on android?

Tags: android, sqlite, relational-database

My latest project is an Android app for monitoring various devices(audio equipment with network interfaces) on a network.

My current thinking is that I will run an Android Service which polls the network/devices every second for any changes and maintains a model of the network state in an sqlite database.

My UI will then query the database as and when it needs information on the network state.

So my questions:

**Does this sound sensible?**

**Is there a better way to model my network using Android-y things?**

**Should I be worried about taking up too much of the system resources with such frequent polling?**

Apologies for the slightly vague, design discussion-type question.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you need to poll so frequently? I'd be concerned about those jobs overlapping.

Battery issues will come up with that much acitivity.

Also - since android relies on wifi you'll have to deal with that connection coming/going.

You might be better suited to setup a machine on the network, let it poll and then query it via android.

Comment: The frequent polling is to get microphone level information and display it to the user in (close to) real time. Having a machine on the network to do the polling for us would be nice (we already have a desktop app for this system) but the current project aim is to have this run without needing a desktop PC on the network.

Comment: Android + WiFi doesn't usually make for great RT processing. Especially for a distributed approach like you are proposing. Though if its just for monitoring and you don't care if it lags or misses updates you might be ok.